# lighting component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

apex class -

```
    List <QueueSObject> queuetype = [SELECT QueueId, SobjectType, Queue.name FROM QueueSobject where SobjectType='LiveAgentSession' and QueueId in: idQueue LIMIT 500 ];
    for (QueueSObject qo: queuetype ){
        String Channel = qo.SobjectType;
        system.debug('Channel---->' + Channel);
        Boolean isEmail=Channel.contains('LiveAgentSession');
        system.debug(isEmail);
        if (isEmail){
            ChannelType = 'Chat';
        }

        system.debug('Type--->' +ChannelType);
    }
    system.debug(queuetype);
    return QueueInfoList;
```

[image]

question is - i want to display "utility-chat" for channeltype=chat otherwise "utility=email",...............How can i do so?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is not correct. It should be like :

`<lightning:iconName="{!queue.ChannelType == 'Chat' ? 'utility:chat' : 'utility:email'}"/>`

Comment: You missed the `{!`  , It would be `{!queue.ChannelType == 'Chat' ? 'utility:chat' : 'utility:email'}`

Comment: nope..this isn't working.....for me now , when i type chat then the new lightning icon is visible but the moment i make the search box empty it is showing me the same icon.

Comment: Your icon should be display based on data (channelType). It should not depend on search keywords. Possible values for channelType are Email and Chat. right?

Comment: yes Pragati... the icon is irrespective of the search box.

Comment: Please check the case of text (`chat` or `Chat`). It is not cased insensitive. If it doesn't resolve then I would recommend you to use `aura:if` tag (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_if.htm)

Comment: does above comment resolved your issue?

Comment: Hi Pragati, No it hasn't resolved my issue..